# i need help to make a text frame

Tags: java, text, frame

is any body knows a code to make a java text frame.,,please i need help

Comment: please let us know what you have tried already that doesnt work.

Comment: i need a code for calculating two numbers by +,-,/,*

Comment: sounds like you simply need help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking but...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
cp.add(new JTextArea());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

^ would be the simplest example.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txt);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
cp.add(scroll);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

^ enables scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField("Should Do your homework first");

JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("Is this homework, \n the queestion is not clear");
```

Comment: :)...that was to be taken in good will in a lighter vien :)